# How to set status to Json array .net?

Tags: c#, .net, json, return, response

I have a webservice that returns json array (JArray) in string format, but I do not understand how to add state value to that operation and get it in the application that consumes the service.

My question is, should I return a json object with a message and inside a json array? Or just an array? hich is more convenient ?

my ws:

```
    public string getList(string strSalary)
    {
        List<Employee> listJson = null;
        JObject jsonResp = "";
        JArray array = null;

        try
        {
            listJson = ReportBLL.getInstance.listEmployees(int.Parse(strSalary));
            array = JArray.FromObject(listJson);

            //set array status ?: ej
            //array status = "succes";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //set error message
           // array status = "error";
           //array message = ex.Message or "Not found employees";
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array);
    }
```

client call (other asp app):

```
 public static List<Employee> listEmployeeClient(string salary)
 {
   JObject jo = null;  //or arrayjson ?
   string strData = "";

   strData = webService.getList(salary);
   jo = JObject.Parse(strData);

 //how to evalue status request ?
 /* example
      if(jo.status == "error") {
          throw new Exception(jo.message);
      } else {
          iterate array inside json object ?
      }
 */
}
```

Is this logic correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new entity for API Response and use it for all your API responses, You can test it out by the following example.

In server:

```
    Class APIResponse<T> 
    {        
        public bool IsError;

        public int ErrorCode;

        public string ErrorMessage;

        public T ReponseData; 
    }

    public string getList(string strSalary)
    {

    List<Employee> listJson = null;
    APIResponse<Employee> responseString = new  APIResponse<Employee>();

    try
    {
        listJson = ReportBLL.getInstance.listEmployees(int.Parse(strSalary));
        responseString.isError = false;
        responseString.data = JArray.FromObject(listJson);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     responseString.IsError = true;
     responseString.ErrorCode = 404; //You can add custom error codes
     responseString.ErrorMessage = ex;
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseString);
    }
```

In Client:

```
 public static List<Employee> listEmployeeClient(APIResponse<Employee> salary)
 {
     //You can access the  model here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `Dictionary<string,object>` before `serializing`, and use `dynamic` to conveniently get the various fields after `deserializing`. `jArray.ToObject<List<Employee>>()` will convert `JArray` object back to the proper type.

Example below:

```
class Employee
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

// serializing
var employees = new List<Employee>()
{
  new Employee() {Name = "john"},
  new Employee() {Name = "alex"},
  new Employee() {Name = "susan"},
  new Employee() {Name = "bryan"},
};

var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
  ["employees"] = employees,
  ["status"] = "error",
  ["errormessage"] = "Not found employees"
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);

// deserializing 
dynamic deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
string status = deserialized.status;
string errorMessage = deserialized.errormessage;

JArray jArray = deserialized.employees;
List<Employee> deserializedEmployee = jArray.ToObject<List<Employee>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. If you have REST apis you can use the HTTPStatusCodes, for each request, e.g. 200 for OK, 400 bad request, etc.

If you want more fine tuning, you can have a general structure of your response objects, e.g.

```
responseDto:
     status:  any code, error or success
     message: any error message
     data:    any expected data
```